# why pass as argument of a function a function?

Tags: c, windows, dev-c++

i have a little question.
i'm studying C with devc++ (as start) and i have seen  as argument function you can pass a function, this is ok but  why?
for example u can write as argument:

```
void myfunc(void(*func)(int)){}
```

but if u simple call function with his name and argument it is not better?

like example:

```
void myfunction (){name of func to call(myargs);  }
```

there's a difference?
it seems the same thing but with more simple and short code

edit:

i want  only know

```
void map (int (*fun) (int),int x[ ], int l) {
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
    x[i] = fun(x[i]);
}
```

why u use this instead of:

```
void map (int x[ ], int l) {
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
    x[i] = nameoffunction(yourargument);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, for example, in [qsort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/qsort?view=vs-2019) which needs a function as an argument? The user function is called by `qsort` to make a comparison of the data items, which are otherwise meaningless to the function, which only provides the sorting mechanism.

Comment: ... or do you mean, where the only job of the function is to call another function? This is done so that the call can be "patched" to another function, or its arguments checked or modified on the way. For example I might intend to write a replacement for a library function, but for now I just call the original function. Please provide an example, as your question has an example of both situations.

Comment: Because: passing the function as an argument allows you to do different things with the same array. You might have one sub-function that increments an `int` and another one that decrements an `int`. You have a function that parses an array and can modifiy each element in the way it is told to.

Comment: nameofyourfunc(yourargs) <---  it's not better than --->  type(*newnamefunc)(typeofargument)? only this thing. it's only less code to write or im wrong?

Comment: @wisepeople You're overlooking the fact that you simply use `function_name(args)` you're stuck with that one function. By *passing* a function as a *parameter*, callers can vary the choice of function to call. It's not that different from passing an `int` parameter rather than hardcoding an integer in your function body.

Comment: The first example allows you to have a "soft" function that can do differnt things to the array. The second example has "hard" coded the function to be called, so this can only do one job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function pointer as a parameter if you want your function to do different things depending on what the user wants.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
    return x - y;
}

int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

int divide(int x, int y)
{
    return x / y;
}

int operation(int x, int y, int (*func)(int, int))
{
    printf("  x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
    return func(x,y);
}

int main()
{
    int x = 8, y = 4;

    printf("x+y=%d\n", operation(x,y,add));
    printf("x-y=%d\n", operation(x,y,subtract));
    printf("x*y=%d\n", operation(x,y,multiply));
    printf("x/y=%d\n", operation(x,y,divide));
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A very good example is the classic sorting function `qsort`. It's a library function, which means that you only have access to it's prototype. In order to make `qsort` general, you have to write your own compare function. A typical implementation looks like this for regular integers:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b ); 
}
```

And then, if you have an array `arr` of integers you can sort it with `qsort(arr, sizeof(arr), cmpfunc)`

You might ask why this is not built in the `qsort` function? After all, it would be easy to make it work for both floats and integers. Yes, but imagine if you have an array of structs that look like this:

```
struct {
    char *firstname;
    char *lastname;
    int age;
} persons[10];
```

How would you sort this? Well, that's not obvious. You might want all three. In that case, write three different compare functions.

Answer (score 0):

> i want only know
>
> ```
> void map (int (*fun) (int),int x[ ], int l) {
>     for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
>     x[i] = fun(x[i]);
> }
> ```
>
> why u use this instead of:
>
> ```
> void map (int x[ ], int l) {
>     for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
>     x[i] = nameoffunction(yourargument);
> }
> ```

Let's answer the question with a question - what if you want to perform more than one type of mapping?  What if you want to map both *x<sup>2</sup>* and *√x*?

You could certainly do something like

```
void map( int x[], int l, int type )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < l; i++ )
  {
    if ( type == MAP_SQUARED )
      x[i] = int_square( x );
    else if ( type == MAP_ROOT )
      x[i] = int_root( x );
    ...
  }
}
```

which works, but is hard to read and cumbersome to maintain - every time you want to perform a new mapping, you have to add a new case to the `map` function.

Compare that to

```
void map( int x[], int l, int (*fun)(int) )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < l; i++ )
    x[i] = fun( x[i] );
}
...
map( x, l, int_square );
map( y, l, int_root );
```

You don't have to hack the `map` function to get different mappings - you only have to pass the function that operates on the individual elements.  If you want to perform a new mapping, all you have to do is write a new function - you don't have to edit the `map` function at all.

The C standard library uses this form of delegation in several places, including the `qsort` function (allowing you to sort arrays of any type in any order) and the `signal` function (allowing you to change how a program reacts to interrupts dynamically).